# KML file upload on OpenLayers map

Tags: 7, javascript, location

When I tested modules in Feb I am sure I got this working but nothing works now; I want the user to be able to upload a KML file when creating a node, and for that to display on a map. I am not even trying to combine multiple, just display each node's KML on an OpenLayers map.

I have tried the following module combinations:

**[Geofile](http://drupal.org/project/geofile)**

This is giving me an error which may just be an issue with the latest OpenLayers version.
Issue on Drupal.org: [EPSG fix is needed](http://drupal.org/node/1973810)

**[OpenLayers KML Layer](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers_kml_layer)**

The instructions on the module make it sound simple but I have not managed to get this to work.

**[Geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/geocoder)**

Module home page suggests that you can set a field to geocode from an uploaded KML file, but I have not managed to get this to work and I do not see any errors.

Does anyone have this working?

**Note**: I know one can define a static KML layer in admin/structure/openlayers/layers, that is not helpful as I need a person to be able to upload a KML file on a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- EPSG is fixed in Geofile 7.x-2.x
- Geofile provides a map formatter for the file field. more [instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1652426)

If you don't want to use the new version of Geofile, then go to the module(sites/all/modules/geofile) folder, open geofile.openlayers.inc in a text editor. if 'projection' and 'displayprojection' are assigned just numbers '4326' or '900913' change it to 'EPSG:4326' or 'EPSG:900913'